# Creating a responsive navbar with two rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, navbar

I am trying to create a responsive Bootstrap 3 based navbar with two rows. However, I am having trouble with the structure of the HTML and the collapse functionality.

Below is a visual description of the desired result, and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction in terms of HTML/CSS (with as much default Bootstrap functionality as possible).

DESKTOP :

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| LOGO | (MD DROPDOWN MENU)|            | A-Option1 | A-Option2 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                       | B-Option1 | B-Option2 |    
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

MOBILE

```
|----------------------------------------|
| LOGO |            |A-Option1|A-Option2 |
|----------------------------------------|
| (MD DROPDOWN MENU)|         HaMBuRGER  |  
|----------------------------------------|
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: where is the code you have tried? edit your question and add it

Comment: I'd just use `@media all and (max-width: Xpx) and (min-height: Xpx)` to detect the width and heigth of a screen and then size the divs that you'd like to be responsive.